# remove duplicate entries in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a json object like this

```
var data = [
      {
        "id": 24,
        "title": "BCOM",
        "start": "2014-08-05 12:59:00 PM",
        "end": "2014-08-05 2:59:00 PM",
        "description": "mcom",
        "DIFF": 120
      },
      {
        "id": 26,
        "title": "MCOM",
        "start": "2014-08-10 12:59:00 PM",
        "end": "2014-08-10 4:59:00 PM",
        "description": "mcom",
        "DIFF": 240
      },
      {
        "id": 29,
        "title": "MCOM",
        "start": "2014-08-11 12:59:00 PM",
        "end": "2014-08-11 8:59:00 PM",
        "description": "mcom",
        "DIFF": 480
      },
      {
        "id": 30,
        "title": "MCOM",
        "start": "2014-08-13 12:59:00 PM",
        "end": "2014-08-13 4:59:00 PM",
        "description": "mcom",
        "DIFF": 240
      }
    ];
```

If you observe here title mcom is repeated, i want to add "DIFF" from arrays if same title is repeated many times, i want to achieve this through javascript. Any one please help me.

My result should be like

```
var data = [
      {
        "id": 24,
        "title": "BCOM",
        "start": "2014-08-05 12:59:00 PM",
        "end": "2014-08-05 2:59:00 PM",
        "description": "mcom",
        "DIFF": 120
      },
      {
        "id": 26,
        "title": "MCOM",
        "start": "2014-08-10 12:59:00 PM",
        "end": "2014-08-10 4:59:00 PM",
        "description": "mcom",
        "DIFF": 960
      },


    ];
```

Thanks

Comment: So what have you got so far? The idea is to help you fix your code, not write it for you.

Comment: Your result doesn't really match what you've got, there is no DIFF that is 960 ?

Comment: am in a total confusion that how to achieve this through javascript

Comment: am saying like if the title is matched i want to add 240+480+24=960

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First Solution** (insecure)

```
var titles = [];
var indexes = [];
var index;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    index = titles.indexOf(data[i].title);
    if(index == -1){
        titles.push(data[i].title);
        indexes.push(i);
    } else {
        data[indexes[index]].DIFF += data[i].DIFF;
        delete data[i];
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

in order to delete items with duplicated titles, we loop on all items of the array. We store new titles in `titles` array and use it to check for duplicated titles. When we store a title we store also the index of the first item having this title in `indexes` table. When we find an item with duplicated title, we add its DIFF to the first element having this title and we delete it.

**Remarques**

using the operator `delete` is dangerous as it makes gaps in the array. Maybe creating a new array to hold new items would be more secure. And then the code would be like this :

**More secure solution**

```
var titles = [];
var uniquesData = [];
var index;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    index = titles.indexOf(data[i].title);
    if(index == -1){
        titles.push(data[i].title);
        uniquesData.push(data[i]);
    } else {
        uniquesData[index].DIFF += data[i].DIFF;
    }
}
data = uniquesData;
```

Comment: Code–only answers are not liked, you should explain your working particularly as the OP has said "am in a total confusion". [*delete*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.1) is an operator, not a function, and it's not a good practice to change a contiguous array to sparse.

Comment: @RobG: I will add explanation, and I use the operator delete only to not create a new array

Comment: is this possible through array map function, because if the array is very big it may cause performance issues..

Comment: Even if it's possible, `Array.map` function contains a loop too. So It's the same thing I guess

Answer (score 1):

Below is a function to do what I think you want. It remembers the title of objects it visits and if it comes across a duplicate, adds the *DIFF* to the *DIFF* of the first instance, then removes the duplicate from the array.

It modifies the original array, though it can be changed so it returns a copy.

```
function removeDups(arr, prop) {

  // Object to store title of visited members
  var obj = {};
  var val;

  for (var i=0, iLen=arr.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    // Store a reference to the current member
    val = arr[i][prop];

    // If have a match
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(val)) {

      // Add the DIFF property to the previous instance
      arr[obj[val]].DIFF += arr[i].DIFF;

      // Remove from array
      arr.splice(i, 1);

      // Decrement counter and limit to account for removed member
      --i;
      --iLen;

    // Otherwise, remember the property value and index of the member
    } else {
      obj[val] = i;
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(removeDups(data, 'title'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var indexCache = {};
var newData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
  var item = data[i];
  if (item.title in indexCache) {
    newData[indexCache[item.title]].DIFF += item.DIFF;
  }
  else {
    newData.push(item);
    indexCache[item.title] = newData.length - 1;
  }
}
```